# How to inherit derived class's subclass form base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

What i have is this code

```html
class A:
    ''' merge all services together '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = 'event'
    
    '''It includes all common method to all services'''
    # TODO inherit these class in others
    class B:
        def __init__(self):
            self.event = 'event'

        def get_event_type(self):
            self.event = 'event'


    class C(B):
        def __init__(self):
            self.event = 'event'
           

        class D(B):
            def __init__(self):
                self.event = 'event'
               

            def get_job_id(self):
               self.event = 'event'
```

Here i want to inherit class D with B but it is getting error

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 16, in A
File "<string>", line 21, in C
NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

So if anyone can help me in this why i am getting this error? even i inherited class C.

Comment: do you want to write classes as Closure or it is just indentation error ? if not closure then imporve the structure

Answer (score 0):

I think its an indentation problem
You can try:

```
class A:
    ''' merge all services together '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = 'event'
    
'''It includes all common method to all services'''
# TODO inherit these class in others
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = 'event'

    def get_event_type(self):
        self.event = 'event'


class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = 'event'


class D(B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = 'event'


    def get_job_id(self):
       self.event = 'event'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is not indentation error. i want to inherit class D which is nested in class C with class class B . and the structure should be same as mentioned in question description.